# promql: How can i find the missing row over a period of time

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a simple query which returns BGP prefixes: `bgp4PathAttrPeer{bgp4PathAttrPeer="10.16.3.9"}`

In my case, this gives me a list of 233 rows (one row per prefix)
If one prefix is withdrawn, same query would return 232 rows instead.
Now my question is, how can I figure out the missing BGP prefix?

I can sum the query and graph them, but that wouldn't tell my which prefix is actually missing, just that one is missing.

[Example result of the query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wucS.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can go to `Graph` left of the `Console`, then increate the time range

[image]